# Why this String() method is called without calling it by name

Tags: go

Consider the following code. The first function is a receiver method for type MessageStr. Why `fmt.Println(msgstr)` executes the first method without calling the method as `fmt.Println(msgstr.String())`. Also why `fmt.Println(msgint32)` doesn't execute the second method.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MessageStr string
type MessageInt32 int32

func (msgs MessageStr) String() string {
    return string("<<" + msgs + ">>")
}

func (msgi MessageInt32) Int32() int32 {
    return int32(msgi * 2)
}

func main() {

    msgstr := MessageStr("Mastering Go")
    // why this outputs <<Mastering Go>>
    // without calling the String() method
    fmt.Println(msgstr)


    msgint32 := MessageInt32(11)
    // why this doesn't output 11*2 = 22
    fmt.Println(msgint32)

    fmt.Println(msgint32.Int32())

}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/VOK9D-rC98D

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/17

Comment: It's documented [here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing)... it's a bit buried under all the other printing rules but you can use your favourite browser to search the page for `String()` to find the relevant text.

Comment: @user815693 For the first case, it is actually calling the String() method since it prints the << >>. Why you say it doesn’t? For the second case, there’s just no standard "Int32()" interface handled by fmt functions.

Comment: @mgagnon because in the first case I do not understand how `String()` is called by `fmt.Println(msgstr)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `fmt.Println`, it expects an object that implements the `Stringer` interface. It's [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) as follows:

> If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be
>   invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be
>   formatted as required by the verb (if any)

The `fmt` package also declares the `Stringer` interface:

```
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}
```

Such objects must have a `String()` method that takes no arguments and returns a `string`. `fmt.Println` then invokes the `String` method. This lets us define for custom types how they're going to be printed out. For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func (p Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s<%d>", p.name, p.age)
}

func main() {
    p := Person{name: "Joe", age: 39}
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Will print out:

```
Joe<39>
```

Because we've customized the way `Person` objects are turned into strings. More details:

- [Interfaces in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9)
- [Stringer in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17)

---

If you're interested in the mechanics of how this actually happens in the `fmt` package, take a look at the `handleMethods` method in `src/fmt/print.go`.